# How do I count the amount of times a word repeats in an array?

Tags: c++

The program sorts the words using qsort.

This is the code I have so far, how do I count the the repeating words? For example, apple repeats twice while main doesn't repeat at all.

```
int main()
{
    //6 entries with 20 max
    char strings[6][20] = { "apple", "apple", "strawberries", "bananas", "dairy", "main" };

    qsort(strings, 4, 20, (int(*)(const void*, const void*))strcmp);

    // display the strings in ascending lexicographic order

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        cout << strings[i] << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could always use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17f3f53996e803f8).

Comment: If you're defining "repeat" such that the one appearance of `main` doesn't count as repeating at all, then logically, `apple` only repeats once (the first occurrence is not a repeat).

Comment: you are only sorting the first 4 strings, not all 6 strings.

Comment: And sorting the list isn't even necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

static const int max_strings = 6;

int main()
{
    //6 entries
    std::string strings[max_strings] = { "apple", "apple", "strawberries", "bananas", "dairy", "main" };

    // sort the strings in ascending order
    std::sort(strings, &strings[max_strings]);

    // display the strings and their repeat counts
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max_strings)
    {
        std::string str = strings[i];
        int count = 1;

        while (++i < max_strings)
        {
            if (strings[i] != str)
                break;
            ++count;
        }

        std::cout << "'" << str << "' appears " << count << " time";
        if (count != 1)
            std::cout << "s";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
'apple' appears 2 times
'bananas' appears 1 time
'dairy' appears 1 time
'main' appears 1 time
'strawberries' appears 1 time
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Buigjs)